# How to make horizontal scolling in bootstrap smaller?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a horizontal scrolling columns in bootstrap but it ends in the far right of the page.How can i do them smaller [image: i want to be on the same level of row above]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
            <div class="container testimonial-group">
               ...
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The css:

```
.testimonial-group > .row {

    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .testimonial-group > .row > .col-xs-4 {
    display: inline-block;

    float: none;
  }

  /* Decorations */
  .col-xs-4 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; }
  .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
  .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
  .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

Comment: remove the container class  <div class="container testimonial-group">

Answer (score 0):

if a understand you question right - try to set css property `overflow: 'hidden'` on "testimonial-group" class

Comment: Not working.I think you understaded well.keep in mind that colored raw is scroolable

Answer (score 0):

try removing the container class

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
            <div class="testimonial-group">
               ...
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```